# Expressing deformation operator as a product

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, differential-geometry

Define an operator $L_{\tau}$ on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ by $L_{\tau}f(x)=f(x-\tau(x))$, where $\tau:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is a smooth function  such that $x-\tau(x)$ is a diffeomorphism on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Suppose $||\tau||_{\infty} = \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^2}||\tau(x)||<\infty$. Can we decompose $L_{\tau}$ as a finite product $L_{\tau} = L_{\tau_1} ... L_{\tau_n}$ with $||\tau_i||_{\infty} < 1/2$ for each $1 \leq i \leq n$, for some $n$ ?

Thank you.

Edit: As mentioned by  Homegrown Tomato (in the comments) the problem is equivalent to proving that an arbitrary diffeomorphism with bounded displacement can be decomposed into diffeomorphisms with small displacement.

Comment: The presence of $L^2$ does not seem to matter: you are asking whether an arbitrary diffeomorphism with bounded displacement can be decomposed into diffeomorphisms with small displacement. Better retag as differential geometry... As far as I know, one approaches such problems by trying to embed the diffeomorphism into the flow of some vector field...

Comment: Thank you, Homegrown Tomato.